# Erro "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esse programa quado executado uma certa quantidade de vezes ele mostra uma mensagem mostrada logo mais a baixo.

## Agente Trem 1

```
    def Ttrem_Um(velocidade,linhas):
        velocidade = randint(55,100)
        return velocidade
```

## Agente Trem 2

```
    def Ttrem_Dois(velocidade,linhas):
        velocidade = randint(55,100)
        return velocidade
    
    def lin(linhas1,linhas2,i,j):
        i = i+1
        linhas1[i] = 1
    
        #   linhas2[j+1] = 2
        #   velocidade =65 - 20
        #   velocidade2 = 65
        return linhas1
    
    def estacao(linhas1,linhas2,linha,velocidade,velocidade2,i,j,z):
    
        i = randint(0,10)
        j = randint(0,10)
        linhas1[i] = 1
        linhas2[j] = 2
    
        print('Trem {} esta na linha: {} \nTrem {} esta na linha: {}'.format(linhas1[i],i,linhas2[j],j))
    
        velocidade = Ttrem_Um(velocidade,linhas1)
        velocidade2 = Ttrem_Dois(velocidade,linhas2)
        print('Velocidade atual: \nTrem 1: {} \nTrem 2: {}'.format(velocidade,velocidade2))
    
        if velocidade != 65 and velocidade2 != 65:
            velocidade = 65
            velocidade2 = 65
    
        print('velocidade atualizada: \nTrem 1: {} \nTrem 2: {}'.format(velocidade,velocidade2))
    
        if(linhas1[i] == linhas2[j]):
            lin(linhas1,linhas2,i,j)
            print('Trem {} esta na linha: {} \nTrem {} esta na linha: {}'.format(linhas1[i],i,linhas2[j],j))
    
    velocidade = 0
    velocidade2 = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    z = 0
    linha = {'Trem_Um':1,'Trem_Dois':2}
    linhas1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    linhas2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    estacao(linhas1,linhas2,linha,velocidade,velocidade2,i,j,z)
```

> ## Mensagem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "estacao.py", line 53, in 
   estacao(linhas1,linhas2,linha,velocidade,velocidade2,i,j,z) File 
    "estacao.py", line 26, in estacao linhas1[i] = 1 IndexError: list 
  assignment index out of range
```

como eu faço para arrumar esse erro?.

Comment: se randint(0, 10) retornar 10 vai dar erro pq a lista não tem o index 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema nesse código é que as listas `linhas1` e `linhas2` possuem 10 elementos que vão da posição 0 até a posição 9 e dentro da função `estacao` você chama `randint(0,10)` para gerar um valor aleatório que será a posição na lista que você irá acessar.

Diferentemente do `range()` o `random.randint` pode retornar o valor de parada. Logo ele pode retornar o valor 10, e essa posição não existe na sua lista.

Para solucionar o problema apenas substitua `randint(0,10)` por `randint(0,9)`.

## Utilizando a função len():

A função `len` retorna a quantidade de elementos que uma sequência possui. Podemos utilizar esta função em listas, tuplas, dicionários, strings, etc.

Pensando nisso podemos substituir `randint(0,9)` por `randint( 0, len(linhas1) - 1)`. A vantagem de escrever o código dessa forma é que você pode alterar o tamanho da sua lista sem precisar alterar sempre o valor que você passa como parada da função `random.randint`. Veja esse exemplo abaixo:

```
import random

def obtemPosicao(linhas):
    return random.randint(0, len(linhas) - 1)

linhas = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

print(obtemPosicao(linhas))

# Uma nova linha é criada e ela pode ser usada sem alterar a função obtemPosicao.
linhas.append(0)

print(obtemPosicao(linhas))
```